# Incorrect permission set received

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, files

In the following shell script:

```
    default_conf_file_path="/etc/apache2/sites-available/";
    default_conf_file=$default_conf_file_path"000-default.conf";
    DocumentRoot=$(grep "DocumentRoot"  $default_conf_file);
    DocumentRoot=${DocumentRoot#*/};
    DocumentRoot=/$DocumentRoot;

    usermod -a -G www-data $(whoami); #modify existing user account by associating it with www-data group
    chown -R www-data:www-data $DocumentRoot; #change the owner of /var/www/html to www-data and the group identifier to www-data
    find $DocumentRoot -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
    find $DocumentRoot -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

I am trying to give permissions to all directories as `2775` and files as `0664`. But the permission set obtained is same for files and directories:

[image]

However, the `files` that are later generated dynamically have the correct privilege of `rw-r--r--`

Why is that? The permission set of all the files have to be `rw-r--r--`

`ls -la` output from the directory I am operating:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 22 08:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root      4096 Mar 22 08:16 ..
drwxrwxrwx  7 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 21 11:02 Common
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 11510 Mar 22 08:16 default_apache2.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    48 Mar 22 08:11 index.php
drwxrwxrwx 17 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 22 08:18 PC
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data  1226 Mar 21 11:02 p.php
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 21 11:02 temp
```

Content `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` (comment lines removed):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: `rw-r--r--` is `0644` in octal notation, not `0664`. And could you please add the `ls -la` terminal output from the directory you're operating on instead of giving a screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander Added.

Comment: Can you post the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`?

Comment: @kos `<VirtualHost *:80> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined`

Comment: Add it to the question please, comments mangle whitespace.

Comment: What happens if you manually run `find /var/www/html -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;` Does that change the permissions? Also, maybe the `$DocumentRoot` variable is incorrect, add a line `echo "($DocumentRoot)" right before the first `find ... chmod` line in your script and run it. What does it output?

Comment: @ByteCommander The output is correct. It is set to `/var/www/html`